# Is there a link parameter that will show me all my published pages?

Tags: permalinks, search, urls, parameter

Is there any way to display a loop of all the pages that are published on my website, via a link? (Even while logged out)

For example, I can type in `domain.com/?s=text` and that will create a post query (search) based on the text.

Are there any parameters to filter it by post type, to show all pages?

I am looking for a solution that only involves manipulating the link. No plugins or code please.

I was looking for a resource of WordPress link parameters, but couldn't find any.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to use custom code or a plugin to do that, if you mean the built-in "Page" (`page`) post type. But you can try `example.com/?post_type=page` in case your site may work with that query..

Comment: Thanks. Itried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: I know, because that's the default behavior. So as I said, use custom code or a plugin.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!